# USing C# Lock inside a viewmodel

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, async-await, locking

I have a UI in which the user can update data. When a field is focused, any text that gets entered goes into a local var used as a buffer, and then as soon as the field is unfocused, the field on the ViewModel is set (using its setter) to the value from the buffer.

Some parts of my UI spin off new threads for processes that I don't want to block the UI thread with, so to avoid race conditions in my code, in the getter and setter for the fields, I use locks:

```
public string TheField {
    get {
        lock(_theField) {
            return _theField;
        }
    }
    set {
        lock(_theField) {
            _theField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, I avoid race conditions between the UI thread and any other threads that may be using the fields.

Sometimes instead of using a new thread, I just use await/async, but I never use `await` inside a `lock` (Of course I don't; I can't, the language doesn't allow it), so there might be a `lock` inside an `await`, but there is never an `await` inside a `lock`.

Is this the right way to do it? Am I understanding how to correctly use locks, or am I accidentally setting up a trap for myself?

Sub-question:

If I have a field that's derived from my first field, do I lock both fields? i.e.:

```
public string FullName {
    get {
        lock(_fullName) {
            return _fullName;
        }
    }
    set {
        lock(_fullName) {
            _fullName = value;
            _firstName = _fullName.Split(" ")[0]; // pretend .Split is expensive so I can't just have FirstName => FullName.Split...
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public string FullName {
    get {
        lock(_fullName) {
            return _fullName;
        }
    }
    set {
        lock(_fullName)
        lock(_firstName) {
            _fullName = value;
            _firstName = _fullName.Split(" ")[0]; // pretend .Split is expensive so I can't just have FirstName => FullName.Split...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't lock on *any* of those fields. You should only lock on instances that 1) can't change over time, and 2) aren't known outside of your object (so that something can't also lock on that instance). Re #2, if you copy a value from one object to another, and subsequently access the property on one object in another thread, it would unnecessarily block the other thread's access to the other object. It's highly unlikely that you need per-property locking; use a private, read-only sync object, `private readonly object syncObject = new object();`

Comment: Also, you tagged [tag:asp.net-mvc] but then you talk about multi-threading the UI. I think you've mistagged.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's the wrong tag, thanks for pointing that out. Ok, so I thought the purpose of locks was to say "I'm using this object right now and anyone else who wants to use it will have to wait". So, since FullName might be accessed by multiple threads, if ThreadB is going to update FullName and needs to ensure that ThreadC can't read the "old value" while ThreadB is working on the update, ThreadB can lock(FullName). Why do I not want to do that?

Comment: It's not that you don't want to lock; it's that you're locking on values that could cause locking that isn't necessary (action at a distance). Furthermore--and specifically in reference to multiple locks in `FullName`--you don't need separate locks for each property. Properties manage the internal state of the whole object, but what you're doing allows for each part of the object to be modified at the same time, so the state could still be made inconsistent by writes to separate properties.